# PHP function SOAP 1.2

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I need some help to execute a SOAP request with PHP.

For example, a method for search a publisher:

```
POST /webservice/search.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.host.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:tns="http://host.com/HostNET/" xmlns:types="http://host.com/HostNET/encodedTypes" xmlns:rpc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-rpc" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soap12:Body soap12:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
        <tns:findPublishers>
          <sessionToken xsi:type="xsd:string">string</sessionToken>
          <expression soapenc:id="id0" xsi:type="tns:SearchExpression">
            <expression xsi:type="xsd:string">string</expression>
            <phonetic xsi:type="xsd:boolean">boolean</phonetic>
            <inflections xsi:type="xsd:boolean">boolean</inflections>
          </expression>
          <distributeurs xsi:type="xsd:boolean">boolean</distributeurs>
        </tns:findPublishers>
      </soap12:Body>
    </soap12:Envelope>
```

I have the `sessionToken` but I don't understand what I have to do with the line `<expression soapenc:id="id0" xsi:type="tns:SearchExpression">` and it's contents.

```
try{

   $search = new SoapClient("http://www.host.com/WebService/search.asmx?wsdl", array("soap_version" => SOAP_1_2));
   $search->findPublishers($sessionToken,???????,FALSE);

}catch (SoapFault $e){
   print_r($e);
}
```

Comment: Writing PHP code from WSDL definition is a boring and error-prone task. There are plenty of generators that will do it for you. For example: https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator. It will generate all required classes for you.

Comment: Have you tried using `stdClass`? I believe something like this might work for second param `$expression = new stdClass();
$expression->expression = "expression";
$expression->phonetic = false;
$expression->inflections = false;`

Comment: While the above comments are sensible practices, I feel like you are asking for advice as to what the values should be. If that is the case, then you will not have much luck here as that is something specific to the API (that we know nothing about) and should thus be provided to you by the API vendor.

Comment: @MichalHynčica with your solution it works now! I understand better thank you!